# create a json like object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to create a json like object in javascript

means:

My object look like

```
var abc = [{ lat: 17.3753, lag: 78.4744, count: 4 }, { lat: 17.3754, lng: 78.4744, count: 1 }]
```

i tried with

```
var feedbackData = [];

for (index in dataCollection.collection) {
    feedbackData.push({
        lat: index.split('~')[0],
        lag: index.split('~')[1],
        count: dataCollection.item(index)
    });
}
```

then i am sending like this **JSON.stringify(feedbackData)** this is not working.

how to create a object like that.

Please help

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you going to send this data?  Can you show us the code that does that?

Comment: after getting all the data i am sending using JSON.stringify(feedbackData) code to another method

Comment: It might have something to do with your `for(.. in ..)` loop. Try using `for (var i = 0; i < dataCollection.collection.length; i++){...}`

Comment: is it `lat` and `lag` or `lat` and `lng`? Your data seems to be inconsistent. I suspect a typo in the field names.

Comment: can you please post a question with your answer

Comment: Please define "this is not working".  I used your above example and was able to stringify it without any problem.

Comment: @Spudley thanks

you can post an answer with your solution
issue :data is inconsistent

Comment: Thanks i can wrong.Thanks for your time.
sorry for use less question

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects already are JSON objects (they were the inspiration for JSON objects).  The array of the object you have already contains two JSON objects.

Comment: can you please explain how can i get a object like Please post a codethat ?

Comment: Yea, except that you can have JavaScript objects that are not valid JSON. _mind blown, I know_

Comment: Thanks i can wrong.Thanks for your time.
sorry for use less question